# ed.onKeyDown in tinymce example

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have newest version of tinymce editor. I have problem, when I want to add section ed.onKeyDown. In firebug console I have error message:

> TypeError: ed.onKeyDown is undefined

Before is my full html file:

```
    <textarea id="txtContent"></textarea>
    <p>Words left: <span id="txtContent-word-counter">200</span></p>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce\tinymce.jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",

    setup: function(ed) {
        var text = '';
        var span = document.getElementById(ed.id + '-word-counter');
        if(span) {
            var wordlimit = span.innerHTML;
            ed.onKeyDown.add(function(ed, e) {
                text = ed.getContent().replace(/(< ([^>]+)<)/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
                text = text.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
                wordcount = wordlimit - (text.split(' ').length);
                span.innerHTML = wordcount;
                if(wordcount <= 0 && e.keyCode != 8) {
                    return tinymce.dom.Event.cancel(e);
                }
            });
        }
    }

     });
    </script>
```

Source:
https://snipt.net/tamewhale/add-word-count-and-limit-to-tinymce/

Comment: are you sure you don't need to wrap it in $(document).ready ?

Comment: I'm not sure... without ed.onKeyDown.add it is working...

Comment: just for experiment , put your `tinymce.init` in `$(document).ready`

Comment: Thank you, I tried it, but it nothing changes.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem migrating from 3.x to 4.x
Solution: http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=107019#p107019

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken, but aren't you trying to bind the the already triggered event "ed.onKeyDown". I would assume or think you would need to bind an object to that event. Also, you should put the init in document ready function as mentioned earlier by  Cherniv.